# I was wondering if it's possible to pass text from an UITextField to SLComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

I was wondering if it's possible to pass text from an UITextField to the SLComposeViewController?

If so that would be nice! essentially I am trying to let the user input his/hers input into the text field and pass the data (text) to the social compose view controller (so the user may share this with Facebook or Twitter) I did manage to pass an image view to the post but I want the user to be able to input text with the post from the text field because I plan on passing the data from my app and have it post to multiple social media (or my own website for the app for instance).

Any help would be appreciated if you want my code to be posted please don't hesitate to ask thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setInitialText` method to add a block of text to the `SLComposeViewController`. It must be done before the `SLComposeViewController` is displayed, but it should allow you to do something like:

```
[someComposerView setInitialText:someTextView.text]
```